# Script que vuelva a otro script

Tags: linux, script

estoy haciendo un script para que cuando entre una persona nueva a trabajar a la oficina, al ejectuarlo le pregunte que software quiere, etc. Lo ideal es desglosarlo en distintos scripts y me pregunto...
Como hago que de un script (llamemosle script 1.2), vuelva a un script del que proviene (script 1.1).

```
    case "$depart" in
        1)
            echo "Seleccionaste sistemas"
            echo "Procederemos a ejecutar e instalar el software necesario para el departamento de sistemas"
            bash sistemas


            ;;

        2)
            echo "Seleccionaste correctivo"
            echo "Procederemos a ejecutar e instalar el software necesario para el departamento de correctivo"
            bash correctivo
            ;;
```

Si se puede evitar, no quiero usar un  "bash nombrescript", porque es guarro con ganas.

El codigo de arriba es el menú, y por ejemplo, me gustaria que cuando un script finalizara, volviera a este otro script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te vale usar `./`? Recuerda darles permiso de ejecución `chmod a+x`.

### script1.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello - 1'
./script2.sh
sleep 0.5
echo 'Bye - 1'
```

### script2.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello - 2'
sleep 0.5
echo 'Bye - 2'
```

### Salida

```
Hello - 1
Hello - 2
Bye - 2
Bye - 1
```